# ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection not working in c# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

I am having two projects one is basically a Windows service and second is class project in which I am doing my business processing. My App.config file is in Windows service project and in my Class project I am using below

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appsettings");           
string scheduledTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScheduleTime"];
```

this setting is in my appsettings section of config file

I am using RefreshSection and also updating my app.config value in windows service project but its not getting updated at run time in my class project.

What is the catch in this ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a little trouble myself with something similar, however I did come across something for AppSettings. Give this a shot:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
```

I think appsettings should be app**S**ettings

Comment: Actually that did the trick for me. Problem was that I needed to pull the configuration for an external DLL by name. That one was cached and the default call failed. After calling it via the name it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get latest value use this code:

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).AppSettings;
var mySetting = appSettings.Settings["keyOfSetting"].Value;
```

remember every time you need latest value, must use two line of code in same place!